# Create "INSERT" statements from mySQL database in Java

Tags: java, mysql

Does anyone know of any good libraries or scripts out there which will allow me to point to any mySQL table and automatically get a list of all the `INSERT` statements for the data in the table? `DdlUtils` allows me to create an XML file from a database model but I would like to have it in `INSERT` statements format and preferably the ability to choose a couple of tables instead of dumping the entire database.

Thanks.

EDIT: I need it to be a Java API because I want to programatically call it from my Java method.

Comment: You should probably try an administration tool like MySQL workbench, Squirrel etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a MySQL stored procedure to generate insert statements on a given table: http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/mysql-stored-procedure-to-generate-extract-insert-statement
No tested though...

Answer (score 0):

[Mysldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) can create inserts statements from  table data.

```
mysqldump [options] db_name [tbl_name ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use DBUnit? Here is an example which illustrates how to export and import: http://dbunit.wikidot.com/demoimportexport

If you don't mind the format of the data files (I'm not sure if it does 'insert' scripts but it definitely does flat files) then it will let you programatically export and import from java.

Although it is built for integration with junit and testing, I don't see why you couldn't use it for any other purpose...

http://dbunit.wikidot.com/
"DbUnit is a JUnit extension (also usable with Ant) targeted for database-driven projects that, among other things, puts your database into a known state between test runs. This is an excellent way to avoid the myriad of problems that can occur when one test case corrupts the database and causes subsequent tests to fail or exacerbate the damage."